# Trouble visualizing what a matrix transformation does to lines(Help with interpretation)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I've recently started studying matrices and linear transformations...I understand most basic matrix working like multiplication etc.

Im having trouble understanding how a linear transformation affects the lines..maybe its the notation but Im fairly confident with that aspect.

However my problem came about when applying a $2 X 2$ matrix to a hyperbola..I'm fine with transforming point what I have trouble with is transforming lines.

Theres two types I'd like help with:

(A) : Given a line set to a constant...like y = a, how to I apply this to a matrix? I was thinking of making a column vector with the top part set to zero and the bottom set to a and applying this to the transformation matrix.

(B) : For that hyperbola example, it was a simple unit hyperbola with its asymptotes : y=x, y = -x.

How do I intepret what these transformations do to lines, with respect to arbitrary constants like y=a and for variables.

Comment: Regarding your terminology: I think in the context of linear algebra it is confusing to refer to something like a hyperbola as a line. I would call this a _curve_ and reserve the term _line_ for a subset of the form $\{\lambda a \mid \lambda \in K\}$ for a vector $a$. Regarding (A): This is a good approach. You will find that a linear transformation maps a line (in the above sense) either to another line, or maps the whole line onto the origin $0$.

Comment: Im sorry, what I meant to say was the asymptote of the hyperbola

Comment: See shifting the asymptotes will shift the hyperbola, so all I need to intepret here is how to apply the matrix to the lines y= + and - x, these were the asymptotes

Comment: This line at the origin would of course be vertical correct?

Comment: On behalf of @mannyglover: The YouTube channel threeblueonebrown does a great job at visualizing linear transformations, in their series "Essence of Linear Algebra": https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZHQObOWTQDPD3MizzM2xVFitgF8hE_ab

Answer (score 0):

As Jendrik Stelzner mentioned, linear transformations map lines onto lines or collapse them onto the origin. However, you must take care that you have the right representation of the line you’re transforming. A single vector suffices to represent a line through the origin, but in general you’ll need two—one ($\mathbf d$) to give the direction of the line and another that gives a point $\mathbf p$ on the line. They combine to form a parametric representation of the line: $\mathbf p + t\mathbf d$. Both of these vectors need to be transformed to find the line’s image. It should be obvious why for a line through the origin the direction vector is enough since you can always choose $\mathbf p=0$ for it.

For example, the vector $(0,a)^T$ doesn’t represent the line $y=a$. You instead need something like $(0,a)^T+t(1,0)^T = (t,a)^T$. The image of this line under the transformation $M$ will be $M(0,a)^T+tM(1,0)^T = M(t,a)^T$.

For part (B), both of those lines go through the origin, so it’s enough to transform a representative vector for each of these lines to find their images.